# Iterating IConnectionPointImpl while connections are changed, got memory access violation

Tags: c++, com, atl

In this code, I get memory access violation on `CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(i);` line:

```
HRESULT FireImpl()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    T * pThis = static_cast<T *>(this);
    int count = m_vec.GetSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pThis->Lock();
        CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(i);
        pThis->Unlock();

        IDispatch* pConnection = static_cast<IDispatch *>(punkConnection.p);
        if (pConnection == 0)
            continue;

        DISPPARAMS params = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
        hr = pConnection->Invoke(2, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return hr;
}
```

I guess that connections are removed when I iterate `m_vec`. Is it valid guess? Should I take care of concurrent firing and subscribing? What happens when I call `getAt` method of `CComDynamicUnkArray` object with out-of-bounds index?

`Lock` and `Unlock` around only `getAt` is common practice I saw in several places. There is no problem with concurrent subscribin. But how can I protect myself from concurrent unsubscribing?

Comment: You made too many assumptions from getting access violation. Unsubscribing is not a problem (you still have `if (pConnection == 0)` line). You might have problem with unsubscribing from wrong thread, single threaded COM object base etc. Or, perhaps even most likely, with wrong COM reference counting, and event invocation on already released object - that would be my best guess in circumstances with no additional details provided.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts! What I learned is that `getAt` returns null pointer if called with too big index and that problem may have root in threading issues.